# display: grid aligning divs

Tags: html, css, zooming, css-grid

I have 3 divs in 3 columns of a grid and I want the middle div to stay static when zoomed in. The one on the right and left growing with the zoom

```
HTML
<mdiv class="dvCenter">
  <div class="dvCenter1"></div>
  <div class="dvCenter2"></div>
  <div class="dvCenter3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dvCenter{
    background-color: black; 
    height: 110px;
    align-items: center;
    display: grid;   
    grid-template-columns: 40% 20% 40%;
    grid-template-rows: 100%; 
}
.dvCenter1{
    background-color: blue;   
    height: 80%;
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
}
.dvCenter2{
    background-color: brown;
    height: 100%;
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 2;
}
.dvCenter3{    
    background-color: blue;
    height: 80%;    
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 3; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to have the page start by having the .dvCenter2 div to have 20% width and then stays as the current width when the page grows. But % is a relative unit and when the screen grows bigger, the 20% is also bigger than the original 20%.

I can't think of a pure CSS way to do this but you can use javascript to query the current size of the container and modify the grid-template-column. Check the demo below. Hope this helps!

```js
$(".dvCenter").css("grid-template-columns", "1fr " + $(".dvCenter2").width() + "px 1fr");
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $(".dvCenter").toggleClass("enlarge");
});
```

```css
.dvCenter{
    background-color: black; 
    height: 110px;
    width: 50%;
    align-items: center;
    display: grid;   
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 20% 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 100%; 
}
.dvCenter1{
    background-color: blue;   
    height: 80%;
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
}
.dvCenter2{
    background-color: brown;
    height: 100%;
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 2;
}
.dvCenter3{    
    background-color: blue;
    height: 80%;    
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 3; 
}

.enlarge {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<mdiv class="dvCenter">
  <div class="dvCenter1"></div>
  <div class="dvCenter2"></div>
  <div class="dvCenter3"></div>
</div>
<button id="btn">Click to resize container</button>
```